# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libvirt?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am a newbie.I'm trying to install the [Cuckoodroid-2.0](https://github.com/idanr1986/cuckoodroid-2.0) and meet this issue in 2 versions of Ubuntu (16.04 and 17.04).

I tried to install `libvirt` with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBRqlr6au2Q) but it still did not work.

Please help me!

Comment: It's `libvirt-bin` as mentioned in the instructions you linked (not the video, please don't do that).

Comment: What I need to do? After I run the command "pip install -r requirements.txt" I meet the error with the libvirt.